# undefined offset when using list explode

Tags: php, list, smarty, explode

im trying to sort categories and subcategories with list explode, but getting

> **Undefined offset: 1**

this is a part of code

```
$squery = $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
$smarty->assign('query', $squery);
list($str, $trash) = explode('&', $squery, 2);
list($category, $subcategory) = explode('=', $str, 2);
switch($category)
    {
        case 'locale':
            $_SESSION['locale'] = $subcategory;
            checklocale();
            header('Location:'.($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '.'));
            break;
        default:
            include 'main.php';
            break;
    }
```

Can you please tell me what i'm doing wrong

Comment: error is on which line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems as if your query string does not have an `&` in it, thus your explode return an array with a single item, causing `list()` to throw the notice.

You probably want to:

- Verify that there is actually a value in `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']`
- Consider using something like `parse_str()` to parse the variables out of the string
- Verify the existence of the values within the query string individually

You also might want to consider the alternative of using `$_GET` instead of `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` to access the parameters more directly. Your current approach is very prone to break if parameters are passed in wrong order.

Comment: The problem is i want to use this list function if it's provided by user (for example http://site/news?year=2013&month=2) but by default script should load main.php, but it doesnt. I've no idea what is wrong. By accessing website with ? and & arguments there is no errors

Comment: The problem is that `explode()` returns an array, not string.  You are then trying , so this array is set to `$str`.  You are then trying to further explode `$str`, which again is an array and not a string so the second `list()` line you have is not working at all.  Again, You should probably just use `$_GET` to look for the specific values you want, or at a minimum use `parse_str()`.

Comment: Thx guys, the best thing to "solve" this problem is to set error_reporting(0);

Answer (score 0):

> Can you please tell me what i'm doing wrong

Well, most of the time I know, `Undefined offset:` errors appear, when you are trying to define an un-indexed character within an array. For example, $var = "foo"; Now, if you were to `echo $var[3];` you would get the same error, because, when 3 is an offset of "foo"; which only has three characters and i.e. from `0` to `2`;

Do to the fact, you have given a limited code, I would suspect the problem to be somewhere `explode('&', $squery, 2);`

Answer (score 0):

you can Do this By only check **locale** is set on QUERY_STRING or not

like

```
if(isset($_GET['locale'])){
         $_SESSION['locale'] = $subcategory;
        checklocale();
        header('Location:'.($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] ? $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] : '.'));

}else{

     include 'main.php';
}
```